# Error cuando elimino un elemento de una lista en c++

Tags: c++, poo, polimorfismo

tengo que hacer un pequeño programa que simule un ecosistema entre animales a lo largo de unos cuantos dias, en si lo que hace el programa es meter un nuevo "animal" cuando se cumplen ciertas condiciones, y matarlo o mejor dicho eliminarlo de la lista cuando se cumplen otras. Todo esto es con una lista de apuntadores para poder eliminarlos de la memoria y de la lista a la vez. Mi problema es que cuando un animal muere y el ciclo for da la siguiente vuelta el programa termina con un error.
Este es el ciclo principal

```
do{
    cout<<"##Dia: "<<acu+1<<endl;

     for (list<Animal*>::iterator it = listaAnimal.begin(); it != listaAnimal.end(); it++){
        cout<<"Animal ["<<animal<<"]: ";
        (*it)->imprimeDatos();
        evento=(*it)->actualizacion();
        if(evento==0){
            cout<<endl;
            (*it)->reproducirse(listaAnimal);
        }
        else if(evento==1){
            delete *it;
            listaAnimal.erase(it);

        }
        cout<<endl;
        animal++;
        system("PAUSE");
     }
     system("cls");
    animal=1;
    acu++;
}while(acu<dias);
```

Tambien dejo los metodos de la clase por si el error viene desde ahi. Esto es con polimorfismo, la otra clase es carnivoros, que practicamente lo unico que cambia son algunos atributos

```
void Herviboros::imprimeDatos() const{
cout<<"Herviboro - "<<sexo<<" - "<<agilidad<<" Evento: ";}
```

.

```
int Herviboros::actualizacion(){
int ale;
ale=rand()%3;
if(ale==0){
    cout<<"Reproducirse"<<endl;
    if(sexo=="Macho"){
       ale=-1;
    }
}
else if(ale==1){
    cazar();
    if(agilidad=="Defenderse"){
        ale=1;
    }
    else{
        ale=-1;
    }
}
else if(ale==2){
    ataque();
    if(agilidad=="Defenderse"){
        ale=1;
    }
    else{
        ale=-1;
    }
}
return ale;}
```

.

```
void Herviboros::reproducirse(list<Animal*>&listaAnimal){
listaAnimal.push_back(new Herviboros());}
```

Perdonen si es un error muy obvio, soy nuevo y apenas estoy aprendiendo:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí:

```
else if( evento == 1 ) {
    delete *it;
    listaAnimal.erase( it );
}
```

Eliminas un elemento de la lista. Sin embargo, según [su documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase),

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Que, en traducción libre por mi parte:

> Referencias e iteradores a elementos eliminados **son invalidados**. Otras referencias e iteradores no se ven afectados.

Es decir, que, si eliminas un elemento de la lista usando un iterador, dicho iterador **deja de ser válido**.

La propia función-miembro `erase( )` viene en nuestra ayuda:

> #### Return value
>
> Iterator following the last removed element.

Al llamar a `erase( )`, esta nos devuelve un iterador al siguiente elemento válido de la lista (que puede ser `end( )`). Podemos usarlo en lugar del recién invalidado.

Por lo tanto, tu código debería quedar

```
else if( evento == 1 ) {
    delete *it;
    it = listaAnimal.erase( it );
    continue;
}
```